# How to make textbox visible when previous textbox contains text

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, visible

I have a WebForm in which i need to place around 30 textboxes mainly to enter barcode scanned data. I am making only the first textbox visible and i want the next textbox to be visible only when the previous textbox is filled with some text. I tried using 'If' condition as well in the textbox on selected change but it doesn't work. Any solutions?

Comment: Isn't the GridView helpful in your case?

Comment: I do have a Gridview which will show the data from these textboxes but in what way could it be helpful ?

Comment: The principle I am talking about is to have one textbox for data entry and a save button. Once validated, it goes in that grid (which can be edited too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use java-script for this because if you will use server side function for this then It will go to server so many times by this your application performance also will decrease.

So create a java-script function that will accept one argument. This argument will take next text box id (text box u want to display).
call this javascript function like this:- onkeyup="calgrid(this,"TextBox2");"
pass nexttextbox id in place of TextBox2...

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

 function calgrid(firsttextbox,nexttextbox)
{

    var id=firsttextbox.id;
    var lastindex= id.lastIndexOf("_");
    var strclnt=id.slice(0,lastindex+1);
    var txtboxvalue=document.getElementById(firsttextbox).value;
if(txtboxvalue!="")
{
      document.getElementById(strclnt+nexttextbox).style.visibility='visible';
}
else
{
  document.getElementById(strclnt+nexttextbox).style.display = "none";
}


}
</script>
```

note:- If you will do visible=false from textbox property then we cannt do visible=true from javascript. So Set style for all textbox style="display:none"

Comment: Thanks Kuldeep ! 
I tried calling the function by putting onkeyup="calgrid(this,"TextBox2");" in my first text box but it is not calling the function...

&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TxtScan1" runat="server" 
onkeyup="calgrid(this,"TextBox2");" ></asp:TextBox  >

Comment: put break point in java-script function. Now run your application in internet explorer. Now you will get to know what is the problem.
I wrote this java-script code into a text file so may be there will be some error. try to solve these small errors

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve your problem by Jquery. 
I have make a sample code where i have take four Textbox. Initially only first text box is visible in Web form, when user enter some values in first TextBox next Textbox is automatically display if Previous textbox have a value if not next textbox is not visible.

Sample code is given below :

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />

$('input:text:not(:eq(0))').hide()
$('input').on("change paste keyup", function () {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
       $(this).next().show();
    }
else
{
    $(this).next().hide();
}
});
```

I have made sample application for same ,please click on given link for Demo

[See Demo application](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/A4wfC/)

It's at Client side code so its performance is so fast rather than Server Side.

Please vote me if you feel your problem is resolved by my idea.

Comment: I don't think this is the best solution he should be using. Having 30 textboxes on the page and managing what should be showing or not... Better have this done dynamically

Comment: Can You elaborate why this is not best solution,i had tried to understand but not able same.

Comment: First you will have to create the 30 texboxes, that will be all rendered but hidden on the page.
Second is the maintenance consideration: what if they want to use later only 20 textboxes?

Comment: If you are creating dynamically controls on forms its act like a container,How to identify which textbox values goes where? I mean which textbox is Product code which one is Serial no.Obviously creating dynamic control you have save page rendering process but what else you are doing lots of code server side and add textbox on form based on condition.On single click or text change event hit the server and iterate Round-trip process. I think its so bad practice to go server again and again to validate each things.

Comment: Thanks Neeraj, but can u plz elaborate on how do i implement it coz i am completely new to jquery.. I have written the cod in<script> as regular, but i dont understand where do i define the <input> tag..
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
and how do i map the textboxes.. Thanks !

Comment: Add Jquery Reference in Head tag " <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>" After that use Jquery Code(Which is provided earlier post) Then create Asp Textbox like That  <div>
            Text1:    
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

            Text2:
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            
        </div>

Answer (score 1):

I'd name these text boxes similarly like "textbox1", "textbox2", "textbox3" so you can easily find the index of current text box. Then you can use KeyDown event to control what will be shown and what not. This is not a working example but it should give you a good direction.

```
        int currentIndex = 1;

        private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox t = Controls["TextBox" + (currentIndex + 1).ToString()] as TextBox;
            t.Visible = true;
            currentIndex +=1;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this i do understand the concept clearly and will try to implement it..

Answer (score 0):

Use can use **Keydown** event in your first textbox

Answer (score 0):

try this code

initially set flag=1 as first textbox is going to be by default visible

> private void visibleTextBox(Control c)
>           {
>               int flag = 1;
>
> ```
>         foreach (Control c1 in c.Controls)
>         {
>             if (c1.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
>             {
>                 if (flag == 1)
>                 {
>                     ((TextBox)c1).Visible = true;
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     ((TextBox)c1).Visible = false;
>                 }
>
>                 if (((TextBox)c1).Text != "")
>                 {
>                     flag = 1;
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     flag = 0;
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Comparatively simple solution in JavaScript. The code should be somehow like this.

Define **onchange** event on text boxes like this:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" onchange="show('txt1', 'txt2');"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server" onchange="show('txt2', 'txt3');" Style="visibility: hidden;"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then use this JavaScript code to show the next TextBox conditionally. Put this code in the head tag of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show(txtCurrent, txtNext) {

        var valueCurrent = document.getElementById(txtCurrent).value;
        //alert(valueCurrent);

        if (valueCurrent.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById(txtNext).style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(txtNext).style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Ali, it is a simple code, i understand it completely but when i try it on it doesn't recognize "onchange".. and can u plz let me kno where you are calling the function ?

Comment: @Rithu well, i have just tested and updated the sample code above. It should work now.